# How to convert some tensorflow code into pytorch version

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I recently started using pytorch. I've been using tensorflow framework before. I have a piece of code that I implemented with tensorflow, which I now want to convert to the pytorch version.

I'm new to pytorch and I'm not familiar with its functions and the transformation process is not smooth, so I'd like to consult.

Here's the code I want to convert：

```
def kl_loss_compute(logits1, logits2):
    """ KL loss
    """
    pred1 = tf.nn.softmax(logits1)
    pred2 = tf.nn.softmax(logits2)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(pred2 * tf.log(1e-8 + pred2 / (pred1 + 1e-8)), 1))

    return loss
```

## python: 3.6, ubuntu: 16.04

logits1 and logits2 are FC layer's outputs. Their shape is [batch, n]

Answer (score 7):

Here is my Implementation (I am taking an example of logits of dimension [3,5]):

**Tensorflow Version:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
def kl_loss_compute(logits1, logits2):
    """ KL loss
    """
    pred1 = tf.nn.softmax(logits1)
    print(pred1.eval())
    pred2 = tf.nn.softmax(logits2)
    print(pred2.eval())
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(pred2 * tf.log(1e-8 + pred2 / (pred1 + 1e-8)), 1))
    return loss

x1 = tf.random.normal([3, 5], dtype=tf.float32)
x2 = tf.random.normal([3, 5], dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x1 = sess.run(x1)
    print(x1)
    x2 = sess.run(x2)
    print(x2)
    print(30*'=')
    print(sess.run(kl_loss_compute(x1, x2)))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.9801388  -0.2514422  -0.28299806  0.85130763  0.4565948 ]
 [-1.0744809   0.20301117  0.21026622  1.0385195   0.41147012]
 [ 1.2385081   1.1003486  -2.0818367  -1.0446491   1.8817908 ]]
[[ 0.04036871  0.82306993  0.82962424  0.5209219  -0.10473887]
 [ 1.7777447  -0.6257034  -0.68985045 -1.1191329  -0.2600192 ]
 [ 0.03387258  0.44405013  0.08010675  0.9131149   0.6422863 ]]
==============================
[[0.32828477 0.09580362 0.09282765 0.2886025  0.19448158]
 [0.04786159 0.17170973 0.17296004 0.39596024 0.21150835]
 [0.2556382  0.22265059 0.00923886 0.02606533 0.48640704]]
[[0.12704821 0.27790183 0.27972925 0.20543297 0.10988771]
 [0.7349108  0.06644011 0.062312   0.04056362 0.09577343]
 [0.12818882 0.19319147 0.13425465 0.30881628 0.23554876]]
0.96658206
```

**PyTorch Version:**

```
def kl_loss_compute(logits1, logits2):
    """ KL loss
    """
    pred1 = torch.softmax(logits1, dim=-1, dtype=torch.float32)
    print(pred1)
    pred2 = torch.softmax(logits2, dim=-1, dtype=torch.float32)
    print(pred2)
    loss = torch.mean(torch.sum(pred2 * torch.log(1e-8 + pred2 / (pred1 + 1e-8)), -1))
    return loss
# same inputs are used here as above(see the inputs used in tensorflow code in the output)
x = torch.Tensor([[ 0.9801388,  -0.2514422 , -0.28299806 , 0.85130763,  0.4565948 ],
                 [-1.0744809 ,  0.20301117,  0.21026622,  1.0385195,   0.41147012],
                 [ 1.2385081  , 1.1003486,  -2.0818367,  -1.0446491,   1.8817908 ]])
y = torch.Tensor([[ 0.04036871 , 0.82306993,  0.82962424,  0.5209219,  -0.10473887],
                 [ 1.7777447  ,-0.6257034,  -0.68985045, -1.1191329,  -0.2600192 ],
                 [ 0.03387258 , 0.44405013 , 0.08010675,  0.9131149,   0.6422863 ]]) 
print(kl_loss_compute(x, y))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.3283, 0.0958, 0.0928, 0.2886, 0.1945],
        [0.0479, 0.1717, 0.1730, 0.3960, 0.2115],
        [0.2556, 0.2227, 0.0092, 0.0261, 0.4864]])
tensor([[0.1270, 0.2779, 0.2797, 0.2054, 0.1099],
        [0.7349, 0.0664, 0.0623, 0.0406, 0.0958],
        [0.1282, 0.1932, 0.1343, 0.3088, 0.2355]])
tensor(0.9666)
```